# Extrair informação de json php

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando coletar a informação contida em "definition", mas estou tendo problemas para acessa-la. (É a minha primeira vez trabalhando com API e PHP)

```
{
    "tags": [
        "hi",
        "hi",
        "hey",
        "hey",
        "greeting",
        "greeting",
        "yo",
        "yo",
        "goodbye",
        "goodbye"
    ],
    "result_type": "exact",
    "list": [
        {
            "definition": "what you say when your talking casually with friends and your mom walks in the room",
            "permalink": "http://hello.urbanup.com/69266",
            "thumbs_up": 3528,
            "author": "mad at the world",
            "word": "hello",
            "defid": 69266,
            "current_vote": "",
            "example": "What the hell(mom enters)-o mom.",
            "thumbs_down": 975
        },
        {
            "definition": "The only word on this site that has nothing to do with [sex] or [drugs]!",
            "permalink": "http://hello.urbanup.com/2269237",
            "thumbs_up": 2123,
            "author": "pirates"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
$json = file_get_html('http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=hello')->plaintext;
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json['definition']
?>
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Estou usando a api do dicionario urbandictionary para coletar  as definições de palavras/expressões, e então eu passei de string para json, só que não estou conseguindo manipular a array para retornar a definição

Comment: esta sendo devolvido em json? usou o [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: sim, como está no code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo que quando você transforma o arquivo em *json* ele se torna um objeto com outras propriedades internamente.

A variável `$json` é um objeto. Você pode acessar suas propriedades desta forma: `$objeto->propriedade`.

'*definition*' está dentro de '*list*' ($json->list), que é um array de objetos.
Você pode percorrê-lo em um `foreach` por exemplo para recuperar a propriedade.

```
<?php
//include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$json = file_get_contents('http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=hello');
$json = json_decode($json);
$list = $json->list;

foreach ($list as $list_item) {
    echo("definition: ".$list_item->definition.PHP_EOL); //PHP_EOL quebra de linha
}
?>
```

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou :\  HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Aqui funcionou, qual erro aparece para você ?

Comment: Aqui tb funcionou.

Comment: Desculpa! Fiz uma coisa errada aqui e acabei alterando o codigo. Valeu!